# Ошибка CS0012 в Unit тестировании с помощью mstest

Tags: c#, winforms, юнит-тесты

Как я понял ошибка выдаётся из-за недостающей сборки System.Windows.Forms ver=4. Но 1. Такой сборки с версией 4.0.0.0 просто нет в диспетчере ссылок. 2. Версии 2.0 и 2.4 положения не изменяют. Все поля тестируемой системы имеют модификаторы public и ссылка на тестируемую сборку добавлена. Данную ошибку выдаёт при каждой попытке обращения к кнопкам и текстбоксам. Помогите разобраться. Платформа теста .NET 6.0, фреймворк тестируемой системы .NET 4.8 . Вот весь код тестирования.

Cама ошибка:

Ошибка  CS0012  Тип "Form" определен в сборке, на которую нет ссылки. Следует добавить ссылку на сборку "System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".

Код:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using CSVWorker;
namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Form1Tests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Button1_Click_LoadsDataIntoDataTable()
        {
            // Arrange
            var form = new Form1();
            var form2 = new Form2();

            // Act
            form2.button1_Click(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            form.button1_Click(null, EventArgs.Empty);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(form.dataTable);
            Assert.IsTrue(form.dataGridView1.DataSource == form.dataTable);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Button2_Click_SavesDataTableToCSVFile()
        {
            // Arrange
            var form = new Form1();
            var expectedDataFilePath = "test_data.csv";

            // Act
            form.button1_Click(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            form.button2_Click(null, EventArgs.Empty);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(System.IO.File.Exists(expectedDataFilePath));
            var savedData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(expectedDataFilePath);
            Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(savedData));
            // Customize additional asserts based on the data you expect to be saved in the CSV file.

            // Clean up
            System.IO.File.Delete(expectedDataFilePath);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Button3_Click_AddsDataToDataTable()
        {
            // Arrange
            var form = new CSVWorker.Form1();
            var initialRowCount = form.dataTable.Rows.Count;
            form.textBox1.Text = "Data 1";
            form.textBox2.Text = "Data 2";
            form.textBox3.Text = "Data 3";
            form.dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
            form.dateTimePicker2.Value = DateTime.Now;

            // Act
            form.button3_Click(null, EventArgs.Empty);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(initialRowCount + 1, form.dataTable.Rows.Count);
            // Customize additional asserts based on the data you expect to be added to the DataTable.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы не должны хотеть тестировать UI, вы должны хотеть тестировать **данные** и **логику**. Условно у вас должна вся логика быть не в классе окна, а в своем классе, под который и пишется тест.